# Facebook login authentication iFrame not loaded properly in safari browsers

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to Facebook app development. Following is my html and script code to retreive access token for facebook users.

I am having a checkbox and on Selecting the checkbox, I need the facebook login authentication form to be loaded.

```
<html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Facebook" name="facebook" id="facebook" onclick="checkFacebookLoginCredentials(this,'fb')"/>
                <div id="fb-root"></div>
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var userFBAccessToken="";

    function checkFacebookLoginCredentials(field, accountType)
    {
        loadFBAuthenticationWindow();       //Function to load the facebook login authentication window
    }

    function loadFBAuthenticationWindow()
    {
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
        {
           FB.init({
              appId      : 'MY_APP_ID', // App ID
              status     : true, // check login status
              cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
              xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
              oauth  : true
           });

           FB.login(function(response) 
           {
                  if (response.authResponse) 
                  {
                    console.log('Welcome! Fetching your Facebook information....');
                    userFBAccessToken  =  response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    console.log('userFBAccessToken: ' + userFBAccessToken);
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) 
                    {
                        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                        FB.logout(function(response) {
                            console.log('Logged out.');
                        });
                    });
                  } else {
                    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                  }
            }, {scope: 'user_activities,user_notes,user_photos,user_videos,user_status,offline_access'});
        };  

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol
                + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());
    }
</script>

</html>
```

When I try to load the above html, I can see the iFrame (Facebook login authentication form) loaded properly in Chrome and FireFox browsers.

But when I tried to execute in SAFARI, the iFrame is not loaded.

Can anyone please say, what I have missed in the above code? Any suggestion please..

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug, especially if this is working in one browser but not the other. Please file this in the bugtracker: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: No.. On investigation, I feel this issue is due to some wrong placement of scripts by me. None face this issue. So can anyone suggest me whats wrong in the above script?